# How to permanently update iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm trying to redirect http traffic to port 8080 on the same machine and have the iptables rules below working.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make this change permanent incase of a reboot of the system.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 server.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66890/how-can-i-make-a-specific-set-of-iptables-rules-permanent

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to do this would be:

```
vim /etc/network/interfaces
```

Append the below line along with your lo directives:

```
post-up /sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables-up.rules
```

Now run the below command

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables-up.rules
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Whoever finds this should consider the much better answer about `iptables-persistent` by yomimono below.

Comment: Never use it this way, that leaves a window open at least for a moment wrong connection can be considered `ESTABLISHED`. Interface should be `lo` (loopback) instead of `eth0` and `pre-up` instead of `post-up`.

Comment: I get a permission denied when trying to write to `/etc`, even in root mode

Comment: Agree with Zakx and Poige, this is one approach out of many but nothing wrong in it. @Poige I had issues with pre-up if there are any errors in iptables-up.rules file hence suggested post-up.

Comment: `pre-up …something_that_can_fail… || :`

Answer (score 136):

Ubuntu (and Debian) offer the package iptables-persistent (Debian: http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/iptables-persistent , Ubuntu: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/iptables-persistent) , which does exactly what you want.  As root, or via sudo:

```
apt-get install iptables-persistent
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

If you're working with `ip6tables`, you'll want to also `ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6`.

You must save the tables again (`iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`, `ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6`) after any change you make.

On older versions (before iptables-0.5, and before Debian Wheezy) you will need write to a different file:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules
```

Comment: In case it helps anyone else... it took me a while to track down that I really needed to do this: iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4

Comment: If you're using IPv6 too, it can be a pain to make sure the rules get to the right place. You can run the following to make that happen, automagically: `invoke-rc.d iptables-persistent save`

Comment: @mdahlman depends on the Debian/Ubuntu version. I believe Debian <7 requires `> /etc/iptables/rules` and 7+ requires `> /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

Comment: @WilfredHughes ahh... that is very interesting. yomimomo, if you update your answer with an authoritative explanation of which versions of Ubuntu need which variation of the command you would be a hero.

Comment: Looks like the change was in iptables-0.5 , from the Ubuntu changelog; http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/i/iptables-persistent/iptables-persistent_0.5.7/changelog , so anything after that will need rules.v4 .

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent

if you want to rerun and save, not ideal but quick and dirty.

Comment: note that you can reload iptables without rebooting just with the command `service iptables-persistent restart`

Comment: Just for the record, the other way is to run `service iptables-persistent save`.  This one and the one suggested by @TedPennings should be preferred way instead of  direct write to destination files.

Comment: You may set iptables values before installing iptables-persistent package. When you install the package, it will pop up for saving current iptables values. So convenient.

Answer (score 6):

Can't we do the same thing with rc.local but perform the following steps

```
iptables-save > current_iptables_rules
```

Then go into /etc/rc.local and enter the following

```
iptables-restore < current_iptables_rules
```

Won't that accomplish the same thing? I could be missing something.

Comment: Yes this should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Add them to /etc/ufw/before.rules. The syntax is a little different but you'll see how it works.

UFW is the Ubuntu firewall frontend to iptables. You might need to enable UFW using `sudo ufw enable`, but you can just not set any rules inside ufw.