# How to change the default port of an EC2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webrick, ipv4

I've got a Rails application running on port 3000 (or any port I want for that matter) and I can access it by browsing to the public ip like so: `1.2.3.4:3000` but I would like to reach the same page by simply omitting the port number, since my domain registrar only allows the public ip, and no port number.  Is there a setting somewhere to direct all incoming traffic from the site to a specific port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this:

- tell rails to use port 80 natively (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351844/how-to-run-rails-s-p80-on-80-port))
- use iptables to forward all port 80 traffic to 3000 (see [here](http://proghowto.com/iptables-redirect-port-80-to-port-8080))
- front your instances with ELB, and port map from 80 to 3000 (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-listener-config.html))

Comment: I was unaware there was an actual command to do this.  The one that worked for me was `sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000`

Comment: Be aware that you will need to reapply this rule after a reboot. For ways to do that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330694/how-to-permanently-update-iptables.

Answer (score 2):

If the url is http and your rails app uses port 80, then you don't have to specify port in the url. 
If your url is https and your rails app uses port 443, then you don't have to specify port in the url. 
If it is not a problem to use any of these two ports, then you can try it.